# Android Fragment/Activity Callbacks: Caller and Callee

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, callback

Recently, while learning Android development, I learned that fragments can communicate with other fragments by defining a callback interface within the fragment and having the parent activity implement it. However, I am a bit confused about the definition of callbacks, so to speak. I learned that callback systems usually have a caller (who implements the interface) and a callee (who defines the interface). However, here this would imply that the activity is the caller and the fragment is the callee. In what manner does the activity "call" the fragment? It always made more sense to me that the fragment was the caller, and the activity was the callee.

For example, take the callback interface setup on android's website:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

It says "Now the fragment can deliver messages to the activity by calling the onArticleSelected() method (or other methods in the interface) using the mCallback instance of the OnHeadlineSelectedListener interface."

Doesn't that imply that the fragment is the caller and the activity is the callee? And that the callee is the one that actually implements the callback interface?

Comment: The caller is the one that receives the `mCallback` instance of your interface. After that, it can always call the callee using that object.